# Change type of paper-input programmatically

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

Is there a way to toggle the type of a `paper-input` programmatically?
I have a `paper-input` element of type `password` and I want to change the type to `text` and vice versa.

This is the element what it looks like:

[image]

This is the implementation of the element:

```
<paper-input id="oldPassword"
             type="password"
             label="Old password"
             no-label-float required>
  <paper-icon-button suffix on-tap="toggleVisibility" 
                     icon$="[[setVisibility(passVisible)]]">
  </paper-icon-button>
</paper-input>
```

This is the JavaScript part:

```
toggleVisibility (e) {
  this.passVisible = !this.passVisible;
  e.currentTarget.type = this.passVisible ? 'text' : 'password';
}
```

The problem is that the type is set correctly but the `paper-input` element didn’t redraw itself.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer by Tony does a great job answering your question.

I'd like to add to it by introducing some more declarative bindings into your element.

See below how I toggle the input type and icon by observing the icon button's `active` property and using it with computed bindings.

```js
Polymer({
  is: 'some-form',
  getPasswordType: function (passVisible) {
    return passVisible ? 'text' : 'password';
  },
  getVisibilityIcon: function(isVisible) {
    return isVisible ? 'visibility' : 'visibility-off';
  }
})
```

```html
<base href="https://polygit.org/components/">

<link href="polymer/polymer.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-input/paper-input.html" rel="import">
<link href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html" rel="import">
<link href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html" rel="import">

<some-form></some-form>

<dom-module id="some-form">
  <template>
    <paper-input id="oldPassword"
                 type="[[getPasswordType(passVisible)]]"
                 label="Old password"
                 value="secret"
                 no-label-float required>
        <paper-icon-button suffix toggles 
                           active="{{passVisible}}"
                           icon$="[[getVisibilityIcon(passVisible)]]">
      </paper-icon-button>
    </paper-input>
  </template>
</dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case, `e.currentTarget` is actually `<paper-icon-button>`, not the `<paper-input>`.

You could reference the password input explicitly with `this.$.oldPassword`:

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      passVisible: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    },
    setVisibility(visible) {
      return visible ? 'icons:visibility' : 'icons:visibility-off';
    },
    toggleVisibility(e) {
      this.passVisible = !this.passVisible;
      this.$.oldPassword.type = this.passVisible ? 'text' : 'password';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-input id="oldPassword"
             type="password"
             label="Old password"
             no-label-float
             required>
        <paper-icon-button suffix
                           on-tap="toggleVisibility" 
                           icon="[[setVisibility(passVisible)]]">
        </paper-icon-button>
      </paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/bwOojb?editors=1010)

...or you could find the `paper-input` ancestor of `e.currentTarget`, which might make sense if you'd like to reuse the button handler for two of these `paper-input`s in the same custom element (e.g., old and new password inputs):

```js
HTMLImports.whenReady(() => {
  "use strict";

  Polymer({
    is: 'x-foo',
    properties: {
      passVisible: {
        type: Boolean,
        value: false
      }
    },
    setVisibility(visible) {
      return visible ? 'icons:visibility' : 'icons:visibility-off';
    },
    _getPaperInputAncestor(el) {
      while (el && el.localName !== 'paper-input') {
        el = el.parentElement;
      }
      return el;
    },
    toggleVisibility(e) {
      this.passVisible = !this.passVisible;
      const input = this._getPaperInputAncestor(e.currentTarget);
      input.type = this.passVisible ? 'text' : 'password';
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <base href="https://polygit.org/polymer+1.7.0/components/">
  <script src="webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer.html">
  <link rel="import" href="iron-icons/iron-icons.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-input/paper-input.html">
  <link rel="import" href="paper-icon-button/paper-icon-button.html">
</head>
<body>
  <x-foo></x-foo>

  <dom-module id="x-foo">
    <template>
      <paper-input id="oldPassword"
             type="password"
             label="Old password"
             no-label-float
             required>
        <paper-icon-button suffix
                           on-tap="toggleVisibility" 
                           icon="[[setVisibility(passVisible)]]">
        </paper-icon-button>
      </paper-input>
      <paper-input id="newPassword"
             type="password"
             label="New password"
             no-label-float
             required>
        <paper-icon-button suffix
                           on-tap="toggleVisibility" 
                           icon="[[setVisibility(passVisible)]]">
        </paper-icon-button>
      </paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-module>
</body>
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/mAaBGv?editors=1010)

Comment: Yup. at first I though that maybe DoK had to use attribute instead of property but it's not the case